# How to render the erase-to-left character ⌫ like desktop in iOS?

Tags: ios, fonts, ios11

The erase-to-left character (⌫) (U+232B) is rendered differently on MacOS and iOS:

[image]

Is it possible to render it like what's on MacOS in iOS app?

Comment: FYI - ⌫ is U+232B. U+2408 is ␈.

Comment: Go to http://iosfonts.com on your iOS device and preview the ⌫ character and see if any the fonts show what you want.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks, updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Particular glyphs are included in particular fonts. The "character" (i.e. the glyph) looks the same on iOS and macOS as long you use the same font. Here it is in iOS with the Arial Unicode font installed:

[image]